# Github from Google Drive

Tags: git, google-drive-api

I use git and github for version control but I also have all my files synchronized with Google Drive. For example, I will have a project in /Google Drive/project/files*, and pull/push to my github repo from that folder.

If I go to a new computer and synchronize my Google Drive without pulling from my github repo, so that I will all my files in the /Google Drive/ project/files*, but it will not have been initialized through git (I did not use `git pull url` ). Should I be able to pull/push/commit this way, or should I only be able to do it after initializing it through git ( `git pull url` ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing your pushing and pulling via ssh, you will need the public keys of the new computer on the server.

Having the repos in google drive will retain all of the repos history.